# $k$-Fibonacci sequence modulo $p$

Tags: number-theory

Let $k$-Fibonacci sequence (generalized Fibonacci sequence) be defined as 
$$
F_{k,n+1} = kF_{k,n} + F_{k,n-1} \space for \space n\geq 1
$$
with initial conditions
$$
F_{k,0} = 0; F_{k,1} = 1
$$

For example, if $k = 3$,
$$
F_{3,n} = \{0; 1; 3; 10; 33; 109; ...\}
$$

I want to get an analogue of Pisano period for this sequence for given $k$ and modulo $p$, $p$ is large Mersenne prime.

Comment: I'd start off figuring out a closed form for the sequence.

Comment: Generating function is $f_{k}(x) = \frac{x}{1-kx-x^2}$ but I don't know what to do next.